# ArcGIS adding opaque circles around coordinates on map

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, mapping

I have an array of coordinates (lat/long). I want to create a coloured opaque (so I can see inside the circle) 500m radius circle for each one and then display on a map.

Is there an easy way to do this? I am new to ArcGIS.

I am using arcgis in python (version 1.8.0). So far I have a list coordinates that result in the following through map:

```
df.spatial.plot(map_widget=...)
```

[image: map of coordinates]

I want the green coordinates to become opaque circles with a given radius so that I can see the rest of the coordinates inside them.

Comment: "ArcGIS" is a rather large platform, and the only tag you've provided is for a product line retired four years back. Please [Edit] the question to specify the *exact* software in use, and what you have tried.